# XSLT - Get maximum child nodes for group of nodes

Tags: xslt, xpath

Is it possible to get the maximum grandchild nodes in all the child nodes, without looping through them?  In the example below there are four document nodes, with 4, 5, 1 and 2 value nodes respectively. So ideally I'd want to return 5 as the answer of the expression / function.

Is this possible without looping in xslt 2.0 or by using xpath?

**XML:**

```
<File>
    <Document>
        <Value>..</Value>
        <Value>..</Value>
        <Value>..</Value>
        <Value>..</Value>
    </Document>
    <Document>
        <Value>..</Value>
        <Value>..</Value>
        <Value>..</Value>
        <Value>..</Value>
        <Value>..</Value>
    </Document>
    <Document>
        <Value>..</Value>
    </Document>
    <Document>
        <Value>..</Value>
        <Value>..</Value>
    </Document>
</File>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the `File` element is the current context item, you could use

```
max(Document/count(Value))
```

`Document/count(Value)` gives you a sequence of integers (the number of `Value` children of each `Document`), `max` picks the largest value from that sequence.

Comment: I missed a node off. But If  all the value nodes were surrounded by one node `<node><value></value><value></value></node>` i could just call `max(Document/count(node/Value))`?

Comment: @iswinky yes, that would work fine.  If it gets too complicated for a single path expression you can use an explicit sequence comprehension operation (`for $d in Document return .....`)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `max(/File/Document/count(*))`.